# Cancelling task from taskschedule cancels all other tasks in it

Tags: task-parallel-library

First of all, i'm really new to multithreading and to tpl in particular, so the code below could be bad. Really bad:)

So, I have following objective:
There is task queue, tasks proceeds inline, and progress of task "working" should be on the ProgressBar.

I was overloaded `TaskScheduler` class:

```
public class MyTaskScheduler:TaskScheduler
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static bool _currentThreadIsProcessingItems;

    private static Logger _logger;

    private readonly TaskQueue _scheduledTasks;
    private readonly int _maxDegreeOfParallelism;
    private int _delegatesQueuedOrRunning = 0;
    public MyTaskScheduler(int maxDegreeOfParallelism)
    {
        _logger = LogManager.GetLogger("log");
        _maxDegreeOfParallelism = maxDegreeOfParallelism;
        _scheduledTasks = new TaskQueue();
    }

    public override int MaximumConcurrencyLevel { get { return 1; } }
    protected override IEnumerable<Task> GetScheduledTasks()
    {
        lock (_scheduledTasks)
        {
            return _scheduledTasks.ToList();
        }
    }

    protected override void QueueTask(Task task)
    {
        lock (_scheduledTasks)
        {
            _scheduledTasks.Enqueue(task);
            if (_delegatesQueuedOrRunning < _maxDegreeOfParallelism)
            {
                ++_delegatesQueuedOrRunning;
                NotifyThreadPoolOfPendingWork();
            }
        }
        _logger.Info("Task queued");
    }

    protected override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
    {
        if (!_currentThreadIsProcessingItems) return false;
        if (taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
            if (TryDequeue(task))
                return TryExecuteTask(task);

            else
                return false;
        return TryExecuteTask(task);
    }

    private void NotifyThreadPoolOfPendingWork()
    {

        ThreadPool.UnsafeQueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
        {
            _currentThreadIsProcessingItems = true;
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Task item;
                    lock (_scheduledTasks)
                    {
                        if (_scheduledTasks.Count == 0)
                        {
                            --_delegatesQueuedOrRunning;
                            break;
                        }
                        item = _scheduledTasks.Dequeue();
                    }
                    _logger.Info("Execution of thread with id {0} started",item.Id);
                    TryExecuteTask(item);
                    _logger.Info("Execution of thread with id {0} ended", item.Id);
                    MessageBox.Show("ggg");
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                _currentThreadIsProcessingItems = false;
            }
        }
            , null);
    }

}
```

And there is the part of code I initialize my queue:

```
 private readonly List<Task> _tasks = new List<Task>();
    readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private MyTaskScheduler _scheduler;

    readonly TaskFactory _factory;

    private int _currentNumberOfThreads;

    public Form1(bool isMainForm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _logger = LogManager.GetLogger("log");
        _isMainForm = isMainForm;
        _currentNumberOfThreads = 0;
        _scheduler = new MyTaskScheduler(1);
        _factory = new TaskFactory(_scheduler);
        if (_isMainForm == false)
        {
            _currentNumberOfThreads++;
            var t = _factory.StartNew(() => DoWork(_cts.Token), _cts.Token);
            _tasks.Add(t);
        }
```

It works perfectly until i try to cancel current task.

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _logger.Info("Initialized cancelling of current thread");
        _cts.Cancel();
        _currentNumberOfThreads--;
    }
```

This canceling not only current task, but all tasks in queue as i can see from logs:

```
01:56:18 Task queued
01:56:18 Execution of thread with id 1 started
01:56:18 Thread's DoWork() begun
01:56:19 Task queued
01:56:22 Task queued
01:56:30 Thread {0} DoWork() ended
01:56:30 Execution of thread with id 1 ended
01:56:31 Execution of thread with id 2 started
01:56:31 Thread's DoWork() begun
01:56:32 Task queued
01:56:32 Task queued
01:56:33 Task queued
01:56:34 Initialized cancelling of current thread
01:56:34 Execution of thread with id 2 ended
01:56:35 Execution of thread with id 3 started
01:56:35 Execution of thread with id 3 ended
01:56:36 Execution of thread with id 4 started
01:56:36 Execution of thread with id 4 ended
01:56:36 Execution of thread with id 5 started
01:56:36 Execution of thread with id 5 ended
01:56:37 Execution of thread with id 6 started
01:56:37 Execution of thread with id 6 ended
```

Task cancellation should cancel only current task and next task in queue should start and work as usual.
I'm really confused and don't know what am I doing wrong. I have an idea that `CancellationTokenSource` I used to cancel my task, refers to the whole schedule, not to concrete task, but I can't prove it myself. So any help will be appreciated.

P.S. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Yeah, seems i'm using a single instance of CancellationToken for all my tasks and when i'm trying to cancel one i raise cancel  request for all tasks. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

It's actually pretty simple:

you are using one single cancellation token as a field.

```
 readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
```

If you want to cancel only one single task, you need to create one token per task, and only cancel the one passed to the task you want to abort. simple as that :)